# iTextSharp: A long cell starts to new page even if there's space in current page

Tags: vb.net, itext

I have a PDFPTable with 2 cells. 
The first one has 1 row. The second one has 100 rows.
The second cell goes to new page but I want it starts after the first one.

```
        Dim cFile As String = "c:\temp\ccc.pdf"

        Dim doc = New Document(PageSize.A4)
        Dim writer As PdfWriter = PdfWriter.GetInstance(doc, New FileStream(cFile, FileMode.Create))
        doc.Open()
        Dim oPdf As PdfContentByte = writer.DirectContent


        Dim baseFont As BaseFont = BaseFont.CreateFont(BaseFont.TIMES_ROMAN, BaseFont.CP1252, False)
        Dim baseFontBold As BaseFont = BaseFont.CreateFont(BaseFont.TIMES_BOLD, BaseFont.CP1252, False)

        Dim courier As New Font(baseFont, 12)
        Dim bold As New Font(baseFontBold, 12, Font.Bold, Color.RED)

        Dim tb0 As New PdfPTable(1)
        Dim cell0 As New PdfPCell
        Dim ch0 As New Chunk("AA")
        Dim ph0 As New Phrase(ch0)
        cell0.AddElement(ph0)
        tb0.AddCell(cell0)

        'Dim tb1 As New PdfPTable(1)
        Dim cell1 As New PdfPCell
        For i = 1 To 100
            Dim ch1 As New Chunk("CIAO")
            Dim ph1 As New Phrase(ch1)
            cell1.AddElement(ph1)

        Next

        tb0.AddCell(cell1)


        doc.Add(tb0)
        'doc.Add(tb1)


        doc.Close()
```

I expect the second cell remains in first page but actual goes to new page

Comment: Did my answer sufficiently help you? Or are there still open issues?

Answer (score 0):

Set `SplitLate` on your table `tb0` to `False`, i.e. add

```
tb0.SplitLate = False
```

before

```
doc.Add(tb0)
```

---

If `SplitLate` is `True` (which it is by default), iText attempts to prevent unnecessarily splitting table rows by postponing a split as long as possible, i.e. *splitting* them as *late* as possible if at all. In particular, if a new row starts on a page which already has content and the row does not completely fit, iText first starts a new page and draws the row on the new page.